# python float class doesn't show up in class hierarchy unless "prodded"

Tags: python, class, floating-point, hierarchy, lazy-evaluation

If I use this function to print out a python class hierarchy for some reason the type "float" doesn't show up in the output.

```
def printHier(cls, indent = 0, tab = "  "):

    print "%s%s" % (tab*indent, cls.__name__)

    try:
        subclasses = cls.__subclasses__()
    except TypeError:
        subclasses = cls.__subclasses__(cls)

    subclasses.sort(key = lambda v: v.__name__)

    for subcls in subclasses:
        printHier(subcls, indent = indent + 1)

printHier(object)
```

If I define this additional function (below) and call it before calling the first, then float shows up.  Can anyone explain this odd behavior?  Is there something lazy about some python classes?  I'm wondering if it might be missing some other classes too.

```
def tweak(cls):
    """
     for some reason "float" doesn't show up in hierarchy unless
     we "prod" it...
    """
    superclasses = cls.__mro__

tweak(float)
```

Comment: What's your version of Python? Your code shows float on 2.7 and 2.6.

Comment: Python 2.6.1 (r261:67515, Jun 24 2010, 21:47:49) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5646)] on darwin

Comment: I also happen to have a 2.6.4 build.  When I use that, I get float without the prodding, and dozens of others that didn't show up in 2.6.1.  Here's a partial list:code
ellipsis
enumerate
frame
generator
instance
reversed
slice
staticmethod
super
traceback
xrange

Comment: Mine is 2.6.4, so I guess this behavior (a bug?) was changed between the versions.

Comment: Confirmed - I just tested with Mac v2.6.1 and float is not present. Works on Ubuntu 2.6.6, Mac 2.6.6 and 2.7.1.

Comment: @Boaz Yaniv - you really should write this up as an answer so that you can both get credit, and so the question no longer shows up as unanswered.

Comment: @Ben: Ok. Didn't think my testing would count as an answer, but for completeness sake I will.

Answer (score 4):

It seems to be a problem with Python 2.6.1. `float` shows on my installations (2.6.4 and 2.7, both on Windows) and on other newer versions tested by Jay and samplebias.

I looked for something relevant in the CPython changelog, but I couldn't find anything that seems to be related.